# close select2 dropdown via javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Good day, How can I properly close a select2 dropdown via jquery or javascript??

for now Im using `select2-dropdown.toggle()` to close it,

but I noticed that It will simply hide the list and the select2 box is still being highlighted [image]

I want to lost focus it or something like that just to close it properly and be able to come up with a result like this one [image].

by the way the screen shots are dark because those select2 boxes are under a bootstrap modal that would come up whenever I press enter.

Any advice would really be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Try -> focus on any other element .

Comment: thank you @TusharGupta for your suggestion, but I already did that, I did set my textbox on my modal to be focused whenever the modal is shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this one works for me `$("#select2-drop-mask").click();`

Answer (score 39):

I know this is an old question but in order to do this using the API you would simply do the following:

**Select2 API**

```
 $("#select2-drop-mask").select2("close");
```

The question also mentions bootstraps modal dialog which tends to be a reason why people want to close it programmatically.

For anyone's info this is how you do that:

**Bootstrap 3**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#select2-drop-mask').select2("close");
})
```

**Bootstrap 2**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
   $('#select2-drop-mask').select2("close");
})
```

Answer (score 16):

In v4.0, none of the other answers worked for me.  Using jQuery to select just the mask had no effect.  I had to use the id of the select box itself:

```
$("#mySelectElement").select2("close")
```

This also worked, but may not be preferred:

```
$("#mySelectElement").select2().trigger("select2:close");
```

[Documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control)

Also, for **Bootstrap 3**, the `hidden.bs.modal` event was too late and the select2 mask would linger for a second during the animation. The `hide.bs.modal` worked a little smoother for us:

```
$('#modalYourModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    //close select2 in case its open
    $("#mySelectElement").select2("close");
});
```

Comment: the second method worked for me on BS5, thanks

Answer (score 9):

The `select2-dropdown-*mask*` didn't work for me, but the below did.

```
$('#select2-drop').select2('close');
```

Comment: @stevemoretz - Is there any way to close them by class? (without needing to use each ID)

Comment: @BeninCA probably by using $('.id').each(function()){$(this).select2('close');}

Comment: @stevemoretz - tried like this, but no go: $('.select2').each(function(){$(this).select2('close');})

Comment: Posted a new question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347627/close-any-select2-dropdowns-via-jquery

Comment: @BeninCA That's why I said probably these stuffs are a bit wired.especially in different versions you get different results.Hope that new question gonna get nice and up to date answers

Answer (score 3):

To close all in Bootstrap version 4 and above. Try:

```
$('body').trigger('mousedown');
```

Comment: Thanks @Ner `$(document.body).trigger('mousedown');` worked for me on BS4

Answer (score 2):

All select2 elements has class `select2-hidden-accessible`. So we can use this class in selector and close all of them

```
$('.select2.select2-hidden-accessible').select2('close');
```

or try to close only one of them with id selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
select2-dropdown.blur();
```

I think this is what you're looking for.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxBa2/1/) you have an example in JSFiddle created by me just now.

Comment: thank your @mbecares for your answer, Thats also what I thought, that I should use blur() function, but its still not functioning. Im using the textbox by the way, because you cant use the select2's ajax function on "select"