# Close ANY Select2 dropdowns via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Anyone know how to close a Select2 programatically **without knowing the ID**? Just basically, if there's a Select2 open, close it.

(If someone opens a modal (containing a Select2), opens the dropdown, and then clicks away from / dimisses the modal, the modal closes but the Select2 continues to show until another click.)

For instance, this works **BUT you need to know the ID**:

```js
// If a Modal is hidden, close the Select2 contained therein
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $("#myDropdown").select2("close");
});
```

And this (selecting by class) doesn't work - at least for me:

```js
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $(".select2").select2("close");
});
```

I know there are other similar topics, but I've reviewed a bunch and am not finding a solution.

Such as this: [close select2 dropdown via javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648246/close-select2-dropdown-via-javascript-jquery)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this figured out. Add a unique (not class="select2") class to all the Select2 dropdowns you have in modals, and then use this code:

```js
// If a Modal is hidden, close any open Select2 contained therein - so it doesn't lag behind
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
   $(".select2-close").select2("close");
});
```

That seems to work well. (In this case I made a class called **select2-close** )